# Intel RealSense SDK 2 voice synthesis

Tags: python-3.x, intel, voice-recognition, realsense

Does Intel RealSense SDK 2 support voice synthesis and voice recognition? Because there are no any examples for this functionality. Because Intel RealSense SDK for Windows supported this functionality.